# IIS Deployment error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am new with ASP.NET, just tried to deploy a default web site - nothing special, but got a error:

An error occurred during publish.
Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Project:
[image]

Deployments settings:
[image]

MySuperSite.pubxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>http://localhost/MySuperSite</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <PublishFramework />
    <UsePowerShell>True</UsePowerShell>
    <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>True</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>localhost</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>Default Web Site/MySuperSite</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>InProc</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>False</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName />
    <_SavePWD>False</_SavePWD>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Do you have `Web Deploy.pubxml` inside your ASP .NET Core project? I think the issue comes from `MSDeployPublishMethod` setting.

Comment: Yes, I have MySuperSite.pubxml. I will put it content in the main question

Comment: Show your pubxml file(s) either from MSDeploy or Web Deploy if your project have any. Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398069(v=vs.110).aspx to know your publish profile.

Comment: I put my publish profile in main question

Comment: Well, try adding this line: `<UseMSDeployServiceURLAsIs>true</UseMSDeployServiceURLAsIs>` in your pubxml file after `MSDeployPublishMethod` element, the `InProc` mode in `MSDeployPublishMethod` seems have impact to URI creation on deployment.

Comment: Did not help, same error

Comment: Any luck?  I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

can you remove the following from the project.json file and see if it works.

```
"commands": {
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls=http://*:5000/"
},
```

Comment: @pimanych : Probably then worth going through this doucment. https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html